# How can I get data read from a database to show in a ListBox using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a databsase called Patients with Table Conditions that has the following fields:

```
ConditionID(PK) int(50) AI,
ID_No(PK)(FK) bigint,
Date date,
Diagnosis varchar(50),
Notes varchar(max)
```

I have a C# windows form application called Records which should read the data in the Table Conditions and show it under the tab Condition in tabcontrol1 in the Records Form.
I have another class called Misc.cs that has the connection string (as my project has many forms and I avoided having the code for connecting duplicated on every form)

Below is code from Misc.cs that connects and reads data from the database:

```
class Misc
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=G:\BiometricSystem\BiometricSystem\Patients.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    public static long Id;

    public void connect()
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
    }

public void getConditions()
    {
        connect();
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Condition WHERE ID_No = '" + Id + "'";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Records r = new Records();
        if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    r.setdiagnosis(dr[0].ToString());
                    r.setDate(dr[1].ToString());
                    r.setNotes(dr[2].ToString());
                    r.printConditions();
                }

            }
            else
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No records to display");

                closeConn();     
    }
}
```

This code is invoked in Records.cs as follows:

```
public partial class Records : Form
    {
        Misc misc = new Misc();
        long patID = Misc.Id;
        private string diagnosis, datum ,dinota;
    public Records()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        diagnosis = "";
        datum = "";
        dinota = "";
    }

    public void setdiagnosis(string dx)
    {
        diagnosis = dx;
    }

    public string getdiagnosis()
    {
        return diagnosis;
    }

    public void setDate(string date)
    {
        datum = date;
    }
    public string getDate()
    {
        return datum;
    }

    public void setNotes(string notes)
    {
        dinota = notes;
    }
    public string getNotes()
    {
        return dinota;
    }

private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                //Nothing to do here
                }
                break;
            case 1://tab containing where I want to display the data
                misc.getConditions();
                //MessageBox.Show("Conditions have been selected");
                break;
        }
    }

public void printConditions()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(getdiagnosis()+"\t"+getDate()+"\t"+getNotes());
        listConditions.Items.Add(getdiagnosis() + "\t" + getDate() + "\t" + getNotes());
    }
}
```

The messagebox shows the requested data, but listbox listConditions does not, I do not know what is the problem.

PS: the messagebox was just to prove to myself that the requested data was indeed returned.
PPS: could you also suugest an alternative of specifying the connection string that doesn't require the absolute path to the solution.

Comment: `Records r = new Records();`  You keep making a new form and then ignoring it.

Comment: Do *NOT* use string concatenation to create SQL commands. Use parameterized queries. And also check your syntax - `BIGINT`s don't require single quotes in a `WHERE` clause, as they are not strings.

Comment: You could put the connection strings in the app.config file and then use configurationmanager functionality to get it when needed.  I would look for example of a good solid business/datalayer set of classes to build off of (disposable, clean, etc) to help you get started. Here is a nice introduction by MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx

Comment: Also take a look at Entity Framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

Comment: @LarsTech when I do that I'm not doing that with the intention of creating a new form. I'm creating an object so that I can access the methods in that class i.e. the Records class, it's just that Forms are referenced in the same way as classes. One solution to this problem is if I remove the code that performs the functionality from the source code of the form and create a separate class for it. That way when I create an object of that class I'm not referring to a form.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I was thinking of encrypting the "Id" field. So I'll change the data type accordingly.

Comment: @user3506908 Your code is a mess though.  Your misc.GetConditions should probably be a function, returning a list of objects that hold the data you want to use in the form.  Misc Class should have nothing to do with a form.  The fact that you have the GetConditions method trying to call printConditions method in the form is a crime.  Separation of concerns is an important concept.  Also, you are trying to use a ListBox to show grid information: you should use a DataGridView instead for that.

Comment: @LarsTech a DataGridView shows everything in the table. I want to show data that has a specific "Id". I tried looking for examples of something like that on the net. I couldn't find. Please point me in the right direction if that's possible. As for printConditions being called in getConditions, I was getting desperate.